# GCM message successfully sent but the smartphone android not received

Tags: java, php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

**I solved it but I no longer have the source code..sorry**

I don't receive the notifications on my Android device. The messagge was sent successfully to the GCM servers. I tried them all. Can someone help me? This is the code:

**GCMIntentService.java**

```
public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {

    static SharedPreferences prefs;
    static Editor editor;

    Context context;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Intent Service";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(Configuration.SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

         if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

             if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                            extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                    // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                                + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    // Post notification of received message.
                    //sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                    sendNotification(msg);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                }
            }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        editor.putInt("lastViewVisited", 1).commit();

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.app_name).toString())
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="<MY-PACKAGE>"
    android:versionCode="9"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!-- GCM -->
    <permission android:name="<MY-PACKAGE>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="<MY-PACKAGE>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- GCM -->
        <receiver android:name="<MY-PACKAGE>.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="<MY-PACKAGE>" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="<MY-PACKAGE>.GCMIntentService" android:enabled="true" />


        <activity
            android:name="<MY-PACKAGE>.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="<MY-PACKAGE>.PreferenceFragment"
            android:label="Preferenze">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**GcmBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    }

}
```

Comment: have u resolved ur issue? can u pls tell how u resolved ?

Comment: yes I solved it but I no longer have the source code..sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Check if you are using the browser api key to send the message from web server to android devices.

Comment: may i need to use browser api key in android side for sending messages from web server to android or may i need to use server key for that @Clear Eyes

Comment: try using the browser key.. for sending the message from your server to android device..